# USB 3.1 Type-A Legacy Connector to USB 3.1 Type-C

Tags: usb

I am unsure of how to design for the following arrangement, any input would be greatly appreciated:

Computer [USB Type-A Connector] -> USB Type-A to USB Type-C Cable -> Custom PCB [USB Type-C Connector] -> HD3SS2522 MUX (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sllses1c/sllses1c.pdf)

As the computer uses a USB Type-A connector, the USB Type-C specific lines are missing (SBUx, CCx). As far as I understand, the MUX uses the CCx lines to determine the cable orientation and route accordingly. Without these lines, how would the MUX be able to know the cable orientation?

---

I missed the part of the USB Type-C Specification which refers to USB Type-C to USB 3.1 Standard-A Cable Assembly Wiring (Table 3-12). It  states that a pull-up resistor Rp (56KOhm) is used on pin A5 within the USB Type-C plug. This will set the source advertisement as "Default USB Power" and also allow the MUX to detect the cable orientation.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the "HD3SS3220 DFP Dongle Evaluation Module" from TI. http://www.ti.com/tool/3220dfp-dglevm

It seems to do everything you want. Here is a block diagram of the components. 
[image]